# Check for tic-tac-toe

Tags: python, list, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a python tictactoe game on a raspberry pi using the sense hat. I have a list that creates the board. I need to find if the list contains 3 rows of rd (the b is turned to rd or (100,100,100)). Does anyone know how I would search the list to see if the columns contain all red(rd) or blue(bl)?

```
   board = [
        b, b, a, b, b, a, b, b,
        b, b, a, b, b, a, b, b,
        a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
        b, b, a, b, b, a, b, b,
        b, b, a, b, b, a, b, b,
        a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
        b, b, a, b, b, a, b, b,
        b, b, a, b, b, a, b, b,
   ]
```

I'm using this to fill the LED's on the Sense HAT, each time the player presses down on the joystick it fills a plot on the grid.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be tic-tac-toe. Do you mean Connect Four?

Comment: Also are you using a 1D list for this, or a 2D list? Your code is a 1D list, but the way you laid it out makes me think it's possible that you're using nested lists (2D) and have simply made a typo.

Comment: 1d list I believe. I'm not really sure since I'm new to python

Comment: Your code as-written here is 1D (just a flat list representing multiple rows with a fixed column-width). The other common way of representing a grid is a 2D list (a list of lists, where each inner list is a single row). Your representation of `board` here, while correct (perfect, even!) made me wonder if perhaps you had lists of lists and simply forgot the inner square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on some assumptions:

1. The a's in your board represent the lines in a tic-tac-toe game
2. The b's represent the play spaces in the tic-tac-toe game
3. An entire 2 by 2 grid of b's will be changed to rd or bl on a play

A method to check a row:

```
def check_row(rowNumber):
    rowStart = rowNumber * 24
    if board[rowStart] == rd and board[rowStart+3] == rd and board[rowStart+6] == rd:
        return rd
    if board[rowStart] == bl and board[rowStart+3] == bl and board[rowStart+6] == bl:
        return bl
    return None
```

I haven't actually tested this code, but it should give you the idea. When called with a row number (0, 1, or 2), it should return rd if the row is all rd, or bl if the row is all bl, otherwise it should return None. Similar methods could be defined for checking a column and for checking diagonals.